# CSS display inline removes Wordpress new lines in paragraphs

Tags: css, wordpress, newline, inline

I have a Wordpress website with posts using `<p>` for text, with a custom style:

```
p {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #555;
    display: inline;
    line-height: 1.2em !important;
    letter-spacing: -.01em !important;
    font-size: 17px !important;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
}
```

I need it to be `inline`, the problem is doing so it removes completely the new lines given through Wordpress visual editor (or even html editor).
How to have both working? is there a way?

Since the posts are managed by another user, a writer for these articles, I'd need to avoid making him write `div` snippets or `</br>` every time.

Comment: why you need it to be `inline`....?

Comment: @Bhuwan cause I have to assign H2 tag to few words inside each post, and to avoid them appearing as an h2 title I assigned a class to the H2 through html and styled through CSS to make it appear as the normal text `<p>` . Doing so the only method I'm aware of to blend the two correctly is to style both `p` and `.myclass` to display: inline.